# Shapefile layer is offset when reprojected to WGS 84

Tags: qgis, shapefile, wgs84, utm

I have some shapefiles in UTM EPSG:37721, however, to cut the variables I need the polygon in WGS84. When I redesign my **square** shapefile in WGS, it appears crooked in QGIS. Is this right? Because if I use this "crooked" square, my variables will come out crooked and, later, I will have to redesign these variables to UTM.

What am I doing wrong here?

Original shapefile in UTM:

[image]

Reprojected in WGS84

[image]

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. That's just how projections work.